# Subtract number from column and add to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I want to do is have a button allows that when clicked takes away 1 from the column 'tickets' in the table 'event' and adds it to the column 'ticket' in the table 'user'.

Code for button

```
form action="sendellie.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Buy tickets"/>
</form>
```

Snippet of Code for processing page (sendellie.php)

```
    <?php
$sql = "UPDATE event SET tickets = tickets-1 WHERE name='Ellie Goulding'";

$sql = "UPDATE user SET ticket = ticket+1 WHERE name = '$uname'";
?>
```

The problem with the code above is that it does not work. It does not take away or add anything.

Any suggestions or tips would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are your columns `integer`? And are your column names definitely correct, as I see you have `ticket` in one and `tickets` in the other?

Comment: Is all that you have in `sendellie.php` file ? Are'nt you taking value from `$_POST` ? Where is `$sql` getting executed ?

Comment: Have you tried running `SELECT name FROM event WHERE name = 'Ellie Goulding'` directly against the database to see if it is returning any rows?

Comment: This has got to be so far from the actual code. I'm not saying you need to provide the entire PHP file, but you certainly need to provide the relevant snippet in its entirety.

Comment: @Ryan double checked and all the column names are correct and integers.